# Non-blocking socket connection over SSL?

Tags: php, ssl

Is it possible to use socket_create/socket_connect over SSL in non-blocking mode?

I'm currently using `\fsockopen()` which natively supports an 'ssl://' prefix. However, `fsockopen()` will block until the connection has been made. This is undesirable in a script that can have around 50 simultaneous sockets waiting to be read.

I've created a test script to use `\socket_create()`, which can be switched to non-blocking mode before `\socket_connect()` is called. However, it doesn't appear to have any support for SSL connections (unlike the `fsockopen()` wrapper).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer would be to use instead `stream_socket_client` with the flag `STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT`; however there seems to be some bug with SSL:

```
<?php
$socket = stream_socket_client(
        'ssl://197.136.197.92:443', $errno, $errstr,
        3, // timeout should be ignored when ASYNC
        STREAM_CLIENT_ASYNC_CONNECT
);
if (!$socket) {
    echo "errno = ".$errno."\nerrstr = ".$errstr."\n";
    exit;
}
```

On Linux there seems to be an infinite loop with:

```
write(3, "\26\3\1\0o\1\0\0k\3\1L\325w/\337u\343uV\341\365}H\331\21k\313\341Q\f\356\""..., 116) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
```

On some BSD variant on http://codepad.viper-7.com/ :

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: SSL: connection timeout in <b>/tmp/cpQ8Gv7B</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: Failed to enable crypto in <b>/tmp/cpQ8Gv7B</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  stream_socket_client() [<a href='function.stream-socket-client'>function.stream-socket-client</a>]: unable to connect to ssl://197.136.197.92:443 (Unknown error) in <b>/tmp/cpQ8Gv7B</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
errno = 115
errstr =
```

See also [bug #49295](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49295).

Comment: `stream_socket_client` worked great, thanks.

One issue is the inability to detect timeouts on async connections. I have posted my workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333398/php-get-socket-error-string-when-async-connect-fails/4114499#4114499

Comment: @Craig Which version are you using? There may have been a bug introduced here recently, because I'm experiencing the problems I've described.

Comment: 5.3.3 on Ubuntu. I'm not seeing any warnings in SSL mode.

Comment: Note that PHP can't handle asynchronous SSL streams.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22003476/1114876