# PHP stream socket not decrypting data

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, encryption

I am trying to set up a secure websocket connection, however my data does not seem to get decrypted. Tried several methods of reading the data, but non works.

Does anyone has a clue what causes this?

**My socket server**

```
//Create the main socket
$context = stream_context_create();

// local_cert must be in PEM format
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/storage/chat/Jongeren.pem');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '*****');

// Create the server socket
$this->master = stream_socket_server(
        "tls://$addr:$port",
        $errno,
        $errstr,
        STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
        $context
);
stream_set_blocking($this->master, 0);
$this->Sockets['master'] = $this->master;

if($errno > 0){ //An error has occured
    log::debug("Main socket error ($errno): $errstr");
    die();
} else {
    log::info("Main socket started, listening on $addr:$port");
}

while(true) {
  //Select sockets witch activity
  $read = $this->Sockets;
  $changed = stream_select($read,$write,$except,1);

    //Process changed
    if( (false !== $changed) && ($changed > 0) ){

        //Accept new connections
        if( in_array($this->master, $read) ){
            $new_client = stream_socket_accept($this->master, 1, $remote_host);
            if ($new_client) {              
                $index = uniqid();
        $this->Sockets[$index] = $new_client;
        $this->users[$index] = new $this->userClass($remote_host);
        $this->ConnectionSettings[$index] = new Connection();
        log::info('incoming connection: '.$remote_host);
        log::info('client count: '. (count($this->Sockets)-1) );
      } else {
                $err = socket_last_error($socket);
        log::debug("Socket error: ".$err.": ".socket_strerror($err), NULL,NULL);
            }
        }

        //delete the server socket from the read sockets
    unset($read['master'], $new_client, $remote_host);

    //Process changed sockets
    foreach ($read as $socket) {

             if( false !== ($buffer = stream_socket_recvfrom($socket,8192) ) ){
                $sID = $this->getSocketID($socket);
                if( empty( $buffer ) ){
                    $this->disconnect($sID, false);
                } else {
                    log::info( 'Data: '.$buffer );
                }
            }
    }
  }
}
```

**The data output:**

```
2015-12-03T21:35:46+01:00 >> Main socket started, listening on 192.168.1.100:9090
2015-12-03T21:35:51+01:00 >> incoming connection: 192.168.1.1:43022
2015-12-03T21:35:51+01:00 >> client count: 1
2015-12-03T21:35:51+01:00 >> Data: lw���ٮ(0�����MO��gyp��³sy��,b7��>��-�F�}ǮsF'g�EMg�c8�
                                                                                                     �F
 �z�F�k{    5�dP�IQ�+��ڞ���~�Q������h5v��Z��FEɸ�� .�~�͉���ªgf\=���Y>�2�
H�_��E�qS��� ����I��.�W
                        /�V �
�Z\���
�u���o�����"�V�)J[���;>�O��y���3?��,��'Ğ-�y�3ݱ1qid�;He�2o�(wyo��C����rt��{[K%�U2�'����"�_�ζA���m
                                                                                                     7�4* ���4ؑ����_���Y�7RO�˝�}J�t���Д�Iݼ`�&KƉ�pƫ,�x�
                                                   �l'~/���NL,��@��<ݿ�U{��'�7r5��w��X�|Va�~f���^���R��5��������Y�K0��.QN�c'�p{-c��߼y�{��Ыr���:ZʬH͞$\�Tl��SQ��*��[���7|#
                                                                               S0�����F���Sh)bL3&�E
      ���czE��J�#��Q.��Q    �����'�E
```

Comment: Not familiar with this, but you're specifying `ssl` as the wrapper in `stream_context_set_option()`, but then calling a `tls://` URL. Have you tried setting both to `tls`? Second thought: do you need to run `stream_socket_enable_crypto()`? I'd imagine the `tls://` URL would do it automatically, but not sure.

Comment: @miken32: triedstream_socket_enable_crypto(), but got the responce it was already enabled for the sockets. Both ssl:// as tls:// give same result

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-recvfrom.php says fread should give decrypted data. I tried that, but didn't work. Will give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: Update: fread gives the same result

Comment: Just came across this (I'm currently doing some socket programming myself, but not encrypted) does the sample code help? It's opening the stream with a `tcp://` wrapper and then enabling crypto afterwards. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22003476/1255289

Comment: @miken32 This only works for clients.

Comment: I had the same symptoms. When using `stream_select` you should really use non-blocking sockets (as I did). But then the encryption will not be correctly set up. To solve that I set the socket temporarily to blocking during `stream_socket_accept` and afterwards back to non-blocking.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it.

```
//Create the main socket
$context = stream_context_create();

// local_cert must be in PEM format
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'file.pem');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', '***');
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

// Create the server socket
$this->master = stream_socket_server(
            "ssl://$addr:$port",
            $errno,
            $errstr,
            STREAM_SERVER_BIND|STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
            $context
    );

$this->Sockets['master'] = $this->master;

if($errno > 0){ //An error has occured
  log::debug("Main socket error ($errno): $errstr");
  die();
} else {
  log::info("Main socket started, listening on $addr:$port");
}

while(true) {

  //Select sockets witch activity
  $read = $this->Sockets;
  stream_select($read,$write,$except,60);

  if(count($read) > 0){
$t = count($this->Sockets)-1;
$r = count($read);
$w = count($write);
$e = count($except);
log::info( 'T:'.$t.' R:'.$r.' W:'.$w.' E:'.$e );
  }

  //Accept new connections
  if( in_array($this->master, $read) ){
$new_client = stream_socket_accept($this->master, 1, $remote_host);
    if ($new_client) {
    $index = uniqid();
    $this->Sockets[$index] = $new_client;
        $this->users[$index] = new $this->userClass($remote_host);
        $this->ConnectionSettings[$index] = new Connection();
        log::info('Accepted connection: '.$remote_host);
    } else {
        $err = socket_last_error($socket);
        log::debug("Socket error: ".$err.": ".socket_strerror($err), NULL,NULL);
    }
  }

  //delete the server socket from the read sockets
  unset($read['master'], $new_client, $remote_host );

  //Process changed sockets
  foreach ($read as $socket) {
$buffer = fread($socket, 2046);

    $sID = $this->getSocketID($socket);
if( empty( $buffer ) ){
  $this->disconnect($sID, false);
} else {
  log::info( 'Data: '.$buffer );
  if (!$this->ConnectionSettings[$sID]->shake) {  //HANDSHAKE
    $this->doHandshake($sID,$buffer);
      } else if ($message = $this->deframe($sID, $buffer)) { //MESSAGE
    $this->process($sID, utf8_encode($message));
  }
}
  }
  //cleanup
  unset($read,$r,$write,$w,$except,$e,$socket,$buffer);
}
```

The problem was that I did not use the right certificate. How stupid of me :(

So these things are important:

- Use the right conntion string that is consistent with the certificate regarding the IP adres or domain
- Have the privatekey, certificate, intermediate, CA in the pem file in this order.
- use fread and frwrite to communicate

Comment: Is there no way to use stream_socket_recvfrom instead of fread and get decrypted data?